# horizontal touch scroll in android brwoser

Tags: android, css, webkit, mobile-webkit

I am trying to use `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` in my web site but I notice it is not working fine in android when `<html dir="rtl">`. If I remove `dir="rtl"` it works fine.

Is there any way to fix this problem with keep using `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` for Safari and Chrome.
Is it a bug with android browser? it works fine on Chrome and Safari

Here is a live demo:
http://jsbin.com/aZeDel/2

Here is screenshots:

Before scrolling

[image: Before]

After scrolling (as you can see there is a white space on the left)

[image: After scrolling]